# JavaScript: Add a delay to each node created

Tags: javascript

Trying to learn JavaScript and this is my first 'real' project.

I am trying to add a delay to each .slice element that is created once the menu button is clicked. The while loop clones and appends  and then the for loop changes the opacity to visible on each slice.

I'm trying to figure out how to add a different delay to each slice node so they appear one after each other instead of all at once.

Do I use forEach after the while loop? Any advice would be great.

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5d2Gc/

JS:

> (function () {    'use strict';
>
> ```
> var m = document.getElementById('btn-nav');
> var a = document.getElementById('main-nav');
> var b = a.getElementsByClassName('background')[0];
> var s = a.getElementsByClassName('slice');
>
> m.addEventListener('click', function() {
>
>   m.classList.add('open');
>
>   var c = document.getElementsByClassName('slice')[0];
>   var sWidth = c.clientWidth;
>
>   while(sWidth < a.clientWidth*(a.clientHeight / c.clientHeight)) {
>
>          var d = c.cloneNode(true);
>
>          c.parentNode.appendChild(d);
>
>          sWidth = sWidth + d.clientWidth; 
>     }
>
>     for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
>              s[i].style.opacity = 1;
>            } 
>
> }, false);
> ```
>
> }());

HTML

> Menu
>
> ```
>           <div class="slice"></div>
>                   </div>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K56XC/)

Instead of :

```
for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
    s[i].style.opacity = 1;
}
```

Use this :

```
for (var i=0;i<s.length;i++) {
   (function(ind) {
        setTimeout(function(){s[ind].style.opacity = 1;}, 1000 + (1000 * ind));
   })(i);
}
```

I have set timeout with every iteration.

Comment: Ahhhh thank you, why did you use ind instead of i? but then use i at the end? just trying to understand

Comment: @user1400803 Because if I use 'i' instead of a anew variable, the loop executes before the first timeout and 'i' shows the value -> s.length. So, we pass the loop variable that sets the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

```
$('ul.side-menu li').each(function() {
                if ($(this).hasClass('link')) {
                    var i = ($(this).index() - 1)
                    var fromTop = menu_head + (i * item_height);
                    var delayTime = 100 * i;
                    $(this).delay(delayTime).queue(function() {
                        $(this).css("top", fromTop);
                        $(this).dequeue();
                    });
                } 
                else if ($(this).hasClass('metro')) {
                    var row_i = ($(this).parent().parent().index() - 1);
                    var col_i = $(this).index();
                    var fromTop = menu_head + (row_i * 125);
                    var fromLeft = col_i * 125;
                    var delayTime = (row_i * 200) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 1);
                    console.log(delayTime);
                    $(this).css("left", fromLeft);
                    $(this).delay(delayTime).queue(function() {
                        $(this).css("top", fromTop);
                        $(this).dequeue();
                    });
                }
            });
```

from http://www.webdesigncrowd.com/demo/side-menu-transition-6.9.14/metro.html

Comment: Page crashes. I think too many .slice nodes are being created. But, that does look like the way it should work.

Comment: http://www.webdesigncrowd.com/demo/side-menu-transition-6.9.14/metro.html check this out it might help you